# Youtube API - worse results than by searching on youtube.com

Tags: api, youtube

I am building last.fm+youtube mashup and I am having trouble retrieving righ results from youtube search.

E.g.
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=Gedz+Gucci%20Gucci%20(feat.%20Joda)&orderBy=relevance

http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=Gedz+Gucci%20Gucci%20(feat.%20Joda)&oq=Gedz+Gucci%20Gucci%20(feat.%20Joda)

The track I am interested in is on the second place in youtube.com search. How I can make api results look as much similar to youtube.com search?

Comment: Thanks! I have not noticed that there were accept ticks. I have thought there are only +/- buttons.

Comment: ping, anyone has any idea? I guess in this example youtube finds only one movie for given keywords and tries to fill the list with similar movies, but how can i make api to show these movies also?

Comment: Have you tried running the search while authenticated as the same user in both cases?  Google tends to like customising search results using user data.

Comment: Tried both searches - the xml feed returns the exact two first videos as the youtube search..

Comment: @SomalSomalski: I'm guessing that Google will return different content based on the cookie. Google should have planted a tracking cookie to find out viewer behavior and suggest/order content based on the relevance to the user's browsing habits.

Comment: Had this *exact* same issue a few months ago. Was not able to get better results from the Youtube API.

Good luck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The method **YouTube** uses for it's provided search results on the home page includes ***Related Videos*** which is based on a proprietary algorithm.

*Unfortunately*, this proprietary method is not yet available in their API (v1 or current v2) which is why you don't have the same results provided.

The YouTube API Page shows how to use the [**Related Videos**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds#Related_Feeds) API feature, but only for a single video since it's limited to that use.

I've seen various questions/replies that come and go on the forum about this issue, like this [*ignored*](https://developers.google.com/youtube/forum/discussion?place=topic%2Fyoutube-api-gdata%2F4A7Ook3dG0Q%2Fdiscussion) one.

Consider using the **Related Videos** based on a ***single video***, which the API does support.

Example of that usage for YouTube Video [***Gedz - Gucci Gucci gość. Joda***](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oepPdNKzxk0) is:

[**https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/oepPdNKzxk0/related?v=2**](https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/oepPdNKzxk0/related?v=2)

You will see **25 results** (default quantity when not specified in query) that are similar but not exact as the single video's YouTube page. Different algorithm's are at play here too, but this method is the best that's currently available.

*My untested solution for your project goal is as follows:* 
**1.** Use current method to acquire video ID feeds. 
**2.** If the results are less than the amount required, use the returned results **first** Video ID as a reference. 
**3.** The Video ID reference (just a single video) is then used to perform another query for Related Videos.
**4.** You can then combine both query's to create a **final list** of **Video ID's** which to use.