# YouTube search results depends on the developer profile?

Tags: c#, youtube.net-api

I am playing with the YouTube API, I have realized that my c# API results are differents than the ones I got when I am using a web browser (firefox) ( I am just searching for general terms like "football", etc)

My questions is the YouTube API "search" results are the same that a user will obtain if he enters in a web browser without login? or like I am using my GoogleAPI.DeveloperKey and username (when I am fill the "youTubeRequestSettings") youtube give me personalized results?

Thx in advance :)

Comment: Here is the asnwer :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769775/youtube-api-worse-results-than-by-searching-on-youtube-com  "The method YouTube uses for it's provided search results on the home page includes Related Videos which is based on a proprietary algorithm.

Unfortunately, this proprietary method is not yet available in their API (v1 or current v2) which is why you don't have the same results provided."