# Youtube API - API search results differ from web search results, and no partial matches?

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am attempting to search through a particular user's uploads for videos matching a query.

When using the web-based search bar on the user's channel page, search results include both full and partial matches.

When running the same query through the API, the results are much more limited. results are more accurate, but other possibly relevant results are filtered out. Is there any way to relax this restriction and return all matching results?

For example,

Querying via the website:

```
http://www.youtube.com/user/EmmaSaying/search?query=ante
```

returns the following videos: 
"ante", "ante quem", "antes", plus words like "anteriority", "antecedent", and "anterior".

The same query via the API (tested on http://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html):

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/emmasaying/uploads?q=ante
```

returns "Terminus Ante Quem", "Antes", and "Ante".

Not only are there fewer total results, but there are no partial matches. Is this simply a limitation of the API? If so, are there any possible ways to work around this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the web you are searching the entire channel (not only the uploads playlist but all the playlists inside the channel)

vs

in the second one you restrict the search with uploads playlist.

I also strongly suggest to use [Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) instead of GData

Comment: Ah thank you! This clears things up, and it looks like v3 should do what I need. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

The method YouTube uses for it's provided search results on the home page includes **Related Videos** which is based on a proprietary algorithm.

Read full text here: [Youtube API - worse results than by searching on youtube.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769775/youtube-api-worse-results-than-by-searching-on-youtube-com)

I hope this algorithm will be implemented in API soon, and it this moment Im prefer to parse results directly from web.